# Is it possible to override the gradle tasks IntelliJ IDEA chooses to run when delegating the build to gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, querydsl

I am using IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1.1.  Builds now delegate to gradle by default.  For the most part, I like this idea but for one of my projects this delegation to gradle seems to be causing a build problem.  I see this in the build output:

```
10:09:23 AM: Executing tasks ':scanrunner:testClasses :policyconsole:testClasses :scanrunner:classes :policyconsole:classes :stepsapi:querydslClasses :service-core:classes :service-core:testClasses :stepsapi:classes :stepsapi:testClasses'...
```

It looks like IntelliJ is choosing these tasks to run automatically from my build.gradle.  The problem is that running the task ':stepsapi:querydslClasses' like this always causes compilation errors.  After running that task in --debug mode, I see that the classpath is just wrong all files fail to compile.  The build will work fine if that task is just omitted like this:

```
./gradlew :scanrunner:testClasses :policyconsole:testClasses :scanrunner:classes :policyconsole:classes :service-core:classes :service-core:testClasses :stepsapi:classes :stepsapi:testClasses
```

When running this way, gradle runs :stepsapi:classes which in turn runs :stepsapi:compileQuerydsl which comes from the querydsl gradle plugin.  I'm assuming there is something in the querydsl plugin that sets up the classpath correctly.

So my question is, is there some IntelliJ IDEA setting or build.gradle setting where I can override which gradle tasks will be executed when a build action is delegated to gradle?

update: Here is a [github project](https://github.com/gclayburg/querydsl-plugin-intellij-fail) that demonstrates this issue.

Comment: `It looks like IntelliJ is choosing these tasks to run automatically from my build.gradle.` what happens when you do Gradle build from command line (`gradlew build`)?

Comment: `gradlew build` on the command line works fine

Comment: Looks command line build does not invoke the `:stepsapi:querydslClasses` task explicitly at all, but IDE does it (as it does it for all source sets in project). It is not possible to change the behavior. When is the Gradle plugin that adds this task? It would be great to get [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to explore the issue and fix it.

Comment: I'll work on creating one, @Andrey.  I suspect that the querydsl plugin and IntelliJ IDEA don't share the same assumptions about how custom sourcesets should behave.

Comment: ok, I created a [simple project on github](https://github.com/gclayburg/querydsl-plugin-intellij-fail) that shows this issue clearly

Comment: Thank you! Filled the https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-211745

Comment: ok @Andrey.  I'm not sure if I would call this an IntelliJ bug or not.  Maybe it would be a nice to have feature to disable or change the tasks IntelliJ chooses to run when delegating the build to gradle, but the answer/workaround I posted essentially does the same thing with some build.gradle tweaking.   Like I mentioned, it is really only needed for gradle plugins that don't share the same set of assumptions about how they will be invoked.

Comment: The "delegate" mode in IDE ideally should have the same behavior as command line Gradle build. If works from command line IDE should also handle it.

Comment: Fair enough @Andrey.  That would be nice for sure.  I'm guessing that IntelliJ chooses the tasks it does for performance.  It tries to only compile the project and avoid other packaging tasks like jar, etc.  It might be tricky for IntelliJ itself to choose tasks for performance and avoid pitfalls of misbehaving plugins.

Answer (score 0):

After messing with this for a while, I'm going with this addition to build.gradle:

```
project.afterEvaluate {
    project.tasks.compileQuerydslJava {
        onlyIf {false}
    }
}
```

This effectively prevents gradle from doing anything with the `:querydslClasses` task that IntelliJ IDEA insists on running.

FWIW, the querydsl gradle plugin extends JavaCompile from the gradle Java plugin.   By doing this, it gets tasks like :querydslClasses and :compileQuerydslJava for free.  The only problem is the plugin doesn't bother to make these "free" tasks work out of the box.  It does, however do some tricks so that the plugin does work as long as you only specify tasks like :build.